# Integrated Paypal with Android Application?

Tags: android, paypal

I want to integrate Paypal into my Android Application.
I have a app with many users. In database, i save total money i must pay to them.
So i will have a Paypal account, and they also have Paypal account.
When users go to my app( must login), and then they click cash out. My app show new page with edittext and button. Users input their email (account on Paypal) and click "Submit" button. Then my app will transfer my money in my Paypal account to this email( this Paypal account).
I also create a developer account on Paypal, i create two account: persional account and business account to test it on Sandbox.
I research many toppic but i don't have good result.
Some resource i found:

http://mobisoftinfotech.com/integration-of-paypal-with-android-application/

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if any of the following link is useful.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

https://github.com/SeraphimSerapis/PayPal-Access-Android-Example

http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-integrate-paypal-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

checkout my open source project : 
PayPal Integration + Node.js server side + Firebase database

https://github.com/OmarAliSaid/android-paypal-example